# Unable to build Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra book in Windows 10

Tags: math-mode, texlive, texmaker, windows

I've been trying to read a .tex version of a free linear algebra textbook:

http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/

**ISSUE 1 is with the repositories:**

My goal is I want to read the .pdf version of the text alongside the .tex version of the text. In this case, there are 3 texts:

1. book.pdf
2. jhanswer.pdf
3. lab.pdf

*In the repositories, they [the .tex files] are undersized dramatically.* Therefore, there is not a way for a person wishing to browse .tex version of these .pdf books in parallel, so I made an issue report. However, that is not the only problem.

None of the repositories have ".tex versions" of the ".pdf" documents. Instead, the .tex files are spread out across a large number of folders and subfolders.

This is the case in both repositories: https://gitlab.com/jim.hefferon/linear-algebra and https://github.com/indraniel/linear-algebra

**Boiling up to issue 2, with installation . . .**

I installed texlive from tug: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

I installed texmaker:
https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html

**ISSUE 2: Even though I installed it through tug, which includes getnonfreefonts, I was missing many .sty files needed to QuickView .tex files.**

> If you installed TeX Live yourself from h**p://tug.org/texlive, then getnonfreefonts will be installed as it were part of TeX Live itself. If the installer is invoked on Windows, it installs getnonfreefonts for Windows only, otherwise for all platforms.

It says I shouldn't have this issue here explicitly: https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

**Boiling up to issue 3, with getnonfreefonts . . .**

> The TEX Live installer contains only fonts whose license allow distribution on DVD. So some are missing where this is not allowed, but which may be used free of cost. Now we install these.

That's what it says here: https://www.latexbuch.de/install-latex-windows/

I followed the installation instructions for Windows, downloaded this link: https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts  and ran the following commands:

```
texlua install-getnonfreefonts 
etnonfreefonts --sys --all
```

However, after doing this, I still get many errors for missing files, such as luximono.sty or bookans.sty (to name a few).

**Conclusion and rationale:**

I'm somewhat learning disabled due to a vision impairment. Typically, I am simply tired of having to Google a math symbol expressed in Hebrew or Greek etc. To work around this, I thought it would be excellent if I could read an introductory text (in linear algebra) composed in .tex so I could search for Latex expressions I don't already know. It's vitally important I know not only how symbols look on the page, but how they sound to the human ear. To clear up this confusion, I wanted a .tex document so I could follow along more easily, but I'm having a lot of trouble.

Comment: imho the repo contains all the files. But they are not organized in way that allows for easy browsing for a casual latex user.

Comment: this seems to be really a qustion that can only be addressed to the author not to a general site like this.  What do you mean by "undersized" for the tex files?  I note the build instructions are supplied as a `make` fiile. You may not have `make` on windows, although versions of make are available for windows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By that I mean the .pdf versions of the texts are hundreds of pages long, while the .tex files found in the repository are vastly shorter, perhaps one or two pages. Even if I did install `make` via `choco install make` (which I just did to verify), I don't have a target `MakeFile` so this instruction also makes little sense.

Comment: there are lots of tex files in the subfolders, and some of them are quite large. E.g. this here is over 2000 lines: https://gitlab.com/jim.hefferon/linear-algebra/-/blob/master/src/gr/gr2.tex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer nothing but errors: https://hatebin.com/jftlstmlno

Comment: well sure, that is not a standalone tex but one of the various input files that the main file use.

Comment: that is perfectly normal for a large document, you use individual files for sections or subsections.  You run latex on the main file and it inputs all the needed ones.  there is a shell script that sets INPUTPATH

Comment: If you ran `getnonfreefonts` and it ran without giving you an error, does `kpsewhich luximono.sty` find the file? Does a search in File Explorer? Does running `texhash` and `updmap-sys` fix the problem?

Comment: You’re not supposed to try to compile the files individually. You’re supposed to run `make` (for which you would need to download a Windows version) from the source directory. This repo was really intended for someone running Linux/UNIX, and support for Windows was not even an afterthought.

Comment: Short of that, it looks like the step you’re missing when you try to compile `book.tex` is that the `Makefile` adds the subdirectories that contain `.sty` files to `TEXINPUTS`, the environment variable that tells TeX which extra directories to search.

Comment: It sounds like you're new to TeX, so I'll spell it out a bit explicitly: when `book.tex` says `\include{gr/gr1}`, then TeX acts as if the file `gr/gr1.tex` was at that exact point.  This allows `book.tex` to be much shorter than it would have been otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The repository is set up to be compiled on Linux/Unix with the `make` command, and support for Windows is not even an afterthought.

Some of the missing files should be installed by `getnonfreefonts`.  On my Windows box, it put `luximono.sty` in a subdirectory of `C:\texlive\texmf-local\`.  Note that this installed a PERL script and I had to install PERL to run that.  There was a typo in the command you posted here, but if you ran `getnonfreefonts` and it installed the fonts without errors, run

```
texhash
updmap-sys
```

Then see if `kpsewhich luximono.sty` can find the file.  If not, see if the File Explorer can.  It’s supposed to go somewhere under the directory you get when you type `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`

An alternative is to download the archive of LuxiMono files [from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luximono) and unpack them into your TEXMFLOCAL directory that you found above (probably `C:\texlive\texmf-local\`).  If you install them this way, you will then need to enable the font map with:

```
texhash
updmap-sys --enable Map=ul9.map
```

The other problem you report seems to be caused by the fact that the `Makefile` tells TeX where to find this project’s `.sty` files by adding them to the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable, a list of extra directories that TeX searches.

You mention that you’re getting an error message about `bookans.sty`.  This file is in the `src/sty/` subdirectory of the repo.  If you installed the files in, **for example**, `C:\Users\WHOMSTSOEVER\Downloads\linear-algebra\`, try:

```
 cd "c:/Users/WHOMSTSOEVER/Downloads/linear-algebra/src"
 SET TEXINPUTS="c:/Users/WHOMSTSOEVER/Downloads/linear-algebra/src/sty"
 pdflatex book.tex
```

Be sure to **change this to the actual path on your machine**.  This is one of the things the `Makefile` does.  If you still get missing files that a search tells you are in your local repo, you’ll need to include more than one directory this way, for example:

```
 set TEXINPUTS="C:/foo":"C:/bar/baz"
```

If any missing files are not in your repo, search for them on CTAN to see what package to install.  However, if you have done a full install of TeX Live plus `getnonfreefonts`, you should have everything you need.

Comment: I was able to install `make` on Windows because of `strawberryperl 5.32.1.1`.



`getnonfreefonts --sys bookans.sty` and seemed to allow me to install the missing .sty but alas it didn't change my experience with Texmaker.

I ran this code and it appears to have produced output though:
`PS D:\Math\latex\linear-algebra\src\sty> kpsewhich luximono.sty`
`c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/luxi/luximono.sty`

Comment: Okay, then the `luximono.sty` is now installed and that error should go away. `bookans.sty` is not part of the `getnonfreefonts` package. It is a file in the `src/sty/` subdirectory of the source archive you downloaded. For TeX to find it, you need to `SET TEXINPUTS=` to the full path of the directory that contains `bookans.sty` and the other `.sty` files in the archive.

Comment: You probably only need to compile once, but if you want, you could also save the necessary commands to a batch file, with a name like `compile-book.bat`. Then you won’t need to look them up again.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me, I was not aware of this post and it is now years later, so perhaps my answer is useless to you.  Anyway, you seem to have gotten wrapped around trying to compile the book to get a pdf.  But the pdf is freely available; for instance look on my web site [hefferon.net](https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra).

As to the TeX source files, they are in the repo that you found.  The first chapter is on Gaussian reduction so the first section's file is gr1.tex, the second section's file is gr2.tex, etc.  The second chapter is on vector spaces so the files are vs1.tex, vs2.tex, etc.  Then comes the chapter on linear maps with map1.tex, etc.  Then determinants with det1.tex, etc.  Finally the last chapter's files are jc1.tex, etc.  (it covers Jordan canonical form).